# No module named numpy on spyder

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, anaconda, spyder

I've checked pretty much every solution available online and none have worked for me, so I'm resorting to asking my own question.
To offer some background I'm writing a GUI in pyqt that needs to connect to serial to take voltages off an instrument we have in our lab.
Anyways, these voltages will read out as an array, so I'm attempting to use the numpy module to help me with this, but for some reason it's saying the module is not found. The IDE I am using is Spyder. I've tried everything from pip3 install numpy to conda install numpy to uninstalling numpy and reinstalling it and nothing has worked. Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions for this. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you pip install numpy?

Comment: @Mitchnoff It reads 'Requirement already satisfied'

Comment: Are you sure you are installing numpy in the right environment? Try doing pip install numpy from within the python console in Spyder.

Comment: How did you install Spyder? Maybe this could help: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder

Answer (score 0):

I normally use anaconda and in an anaconda virtual environment, I type the following commands:

```
pip install numpy
pip install spyder
spyder
```

This should open your spyder app and any code you write should be able to import and use numpy successfully. Hope this helps.